# Installing emacs for mac from sources: execute ./configure but 'no such file or directory'

Tags: macos, git, emacs

I'm a beginner in this area. I have cloned the sources of emacs from github. As stated in INSTALL file, I executed ./configure but the terminal showed 'no such file or directory'.

I checked the files. There are two similar files, configure.in and config.bat. I don't know whether these two files is relevant to the installment.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest emacs sources aren't compatible with the autotools shipped with OSX, so you can't generate `./configure` in the usual way. However, the developers have provided a workaround by allowing you to run the following in the root of the emacs source tree:

```
./autogen/copy_autogen
```

After that, go ahead with the usual

```
./configure --with-ns --without-dbus
```

or similar.

Also, I'm not sure that there's an up-to-date mirror of the emacs sources on github. If you're set on using git instead of bzr (the "native" SCM for emacs developers), clone the following (more official) repo instead:

```
http://git.sv.gnu.org/r/emacs.git
```

A good choice might be to use a Mac package manager like [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), with which you can install the latest emacs code like this:

```
brew install --head emacs
```

But as Chris says, definitely consider downloading a nightly build from [emacsformacosx.com](https://emacsformacosx.com/builds) instead.

Comment: I did as you stated and it worked! I may try Chris's suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't give a specific link to the source code you're trying to build.
Also, if you're a beginner maybe you should use a pre-built package for OSX?

Anyway, configure is probably missing because the autoconf tools weren't run.  Quickly consulting the Emacs repository from the GNU page, I think this link should state what you need to know.

http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/INSTALL.BZR

Chris

Comment: The link is very useful for solving my problem. Thanks.